# How do I take specific data from multiple excel files and append it into a new excel file without deleting the data I already have with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

location = 'C:\\projects\*.xlsx'
excel_files = glob.glob(location)

df0 = pd.DataFrame()

for excel_file in excel_files:
    df00 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    df0 = pd.concat([df0.iloc[2:3, 0:10], df00.iloc[2:3, 0:10]], ignore_index = True)

df0.to_excel('C:\\Project Results\Project_Results.xlsx', index = False)
print(df0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#instantiate outside for loop
df0 = pd.DataFrame()
df0 = df0.iloc[2:3,0:10]
```

inside the for loop, replace pd.concat with append as follow:

```
df0 = df0.append([df00.iloc[2:3,0:10]], ignore_index=True)
```